# How to get a entity by ID ngrx

Tags: redux, ngrx

I have the following store

```
export const featureAdapter: EntityAdapter<IProduct> = createEntityAdapter<IProduct>({
  selectId: model => model.id,
});

export interface State extends EntityState<IProduct> {
  selectedProduct?: IProduct;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  error?: any;
}

export const initialState: State = featureAdapter.getInitialState({
  selectedProduct: IProduct,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null
});
```

I would like that my selected product always point on a Entity and get updates with it. I believe since actions are always creating new object, the link is not possible, I decided to change the selectedProduct from a reference to a simple id.

```
export const initialState: State = featureAdapter.getInitialState({
  selectedProduct: string,
  isLoading: false,
  error: null
});
```

but how do i retrieve my entity with the same ID, and get updates on my observable if it is changed ?

I tried

```
export const getSelectedProduct: MemoizedSelector<object, any> = createSelector(
  selectAllEntities,
  selectedProduct,
  (entities, id) => entities[id]
);


export const selectEntityById = createSelector(
  selectAllEntities,
  (entities, props) => entities[props.id]
);
```

my questions are 
Is this the only way to select an entity by id ?

```
this.store$.pipe(
  select(ProductStoreSelectors.selectEntityById, { id: product.id }),
  map(product => console.log(product))
)
```

and
      this.store$.select(ProductStoreSelectors.getSelectedProduct).subscribe((product: string) => {
        console.log(product)
      }),

this never trigger when I change my selected product Id

EDIT :

the reducer on select do the following

```
const SET_SELECTED_PRODUCT = (state: State, action: featureAction.SetSelectedProduct) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    selectedProduct: action.payload.product.id
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your selector:

```
export const selectEntityById = (id: number) => createSelector(
  selectAllEntities,
  (entities) => entities[id]
);
```

and your select:

```
select(ProductStoreSelectors.selectEntityById(id))
```